# SML in list parameter functions

Tags: sml

I had two parameters. The first one was list, and the other was integer n. 
Our function formed a new list which contained the first n elements of the parameter list and suppose that n

```
([1,2,3,4],2 )  
  [1,2]
```

How do I do that only using `->  nil, ::, @` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is `List.take` function in SML basis library:

```
List.take ([1,2,3,4],2 )
[1,2]
```

If you want to make the function yourself:

```
fun take ([], _) = []
  | take (_, 0)  = []
  | take (x::xs, n) = x::take(xs, n-1)
```

Or to demonstrate the use of `-> nil, ::, @` (the use of `@` is not recommended, just for illustration purpose):

```
fun take (nil, _) = nil
  | take (_, 0)  = nil
  | take (x::xs, n) = [x] @ take(xs, n-1)
```

Comment: of course how i do that different way ? I thought your response. I'm looking at another solution can you help me?

Comment: (nil, _)  _  using of this. what does it mean ?

Comment: That is wildcard pattern; it means you don't care about its value.

Comment: _ instead of this . do i use another option ?

Comment: Just put a variable as usual, no difference at all: 
fun take (nil, n) = nil
  | take (xs, 0)  = nil
  | take (x::xs, n) = [x] @ take(xs, n-1)

Comment: @lutzlover: _ is a wildcard, and "works" the same way as an variable, however as long as it is newer referenced on the right hand side of the function clause, there is no need to bind the value to a variable (as it is newer being used).

Comment: @pad, You properly mean the sml basis library, and not basis sml library. Your use of append (@) in that example is very bad coding style (i know he almost asked for it), however there is no need to show bad habits.